# jquery overscroll.js module, infinite scroll issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, overscroll

I'm using this plugin http://azoff.github.io/overscroll/

My problem is that sometimes the scroll is infinite (you can keep scrolling even when there are no more elements).

I'm not exactly sure how and when this occurs so i would like to know if anyone already encountered this problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to set a height for the container AND the inner éléments